# Reading file from another system in node.js

Tags: node.js, remote-access, remote-desktop

Can anyone provide me some solution to read files from a remote machine in node.js.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You may want [jsDav](https://github.com/mikedeboer/jsdav) and [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is out the range of node.js, you can have a look at how to mount remote filesystem to local, such as nfs, sshfs. After mounted to local machine, you can read/write it with fs module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot !
I have found a way to remote read the file using java, with this i get the file from remote system on my system. 
And ill create a jar of this and use it in my node.js code.

P.S- i did find a similar node module for the java library (VFS local) which i am using, however i had some installation issues with the node modules - vfs-local and pty.cc (vfs-local depends on pty.cc and pty.cc was giving me some errors while installing )

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to read a file over file protocol. If you want to read a file or fetch file data over file protocol, then checkout below code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { URL } = require('url');
const fileUrl = new URL('file://tmp/hello.txt');

fs.readFileSync(fileUrl);
```

Also go through Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_whatwg_url_object_support).